# PDO queries with integer type

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

From PHP, i am querying MySQL database using PDO. Query is

```
$id = 5;
$stmt = $con >prepare("select name from employee where id= ? "); 
$stmt ->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

This is working as expected and the name of the employee with id 5 is fetched. However from the logs I could see that the query actually executed is

`select name from employee where id= '5'`

id was int type and binding was done using PDO::PARAM_INT. so the query executed should have been `id= 5` and not `id= '5'`. MySql had to possibly covert string to int due to this,

Is this expected behavior with PDO or is there an error in my understanding?

Comment: `However from the logs` - logs of which system? MySQL? PHP? Some custom logger?

Comment: I use mysql logs

Comment: So, If I'm not mistaken, MySQL might be quoting integer values in its logs. It's easy to verify whether I'm right or wrong - simply run a query from MySQL terminal and check if ints get quoted or not in the logs. If not, excellent, PHP is to blame (emulated prepares and potential lack of mysqlnd). If it is quoted, then MySQL simply quotes all parameters for logging purposes.

Comment: @Kiran I'm curious, is this the first time that this happens?

Comment: i have been using pdo for long. but today i enabled logs to analyze queries and then noted this thing. I believe the behavior was same all the time. I searched similar questions and could not find any. so i was under the impression that i am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly a bug in PHP, [this ticket](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44639) or related to [this one](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73234). A [commit](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=32b6154a61fae820386527f3019f8c5937fc5d27) to fix this bug have been submitted (Tue, 11 Oct 2016), wich says :

> The prepared statement emulator (pdo_sql_parser.*) figures out how to quote
>   each query parameter. The intended type is specified by the PDO::PARAM_*
>   consts, but this direction wasn't always followed

What is your version of PHP? An update can probably fix it.

Comment: my php version is 5.6.31

Comment: I've read on github that the fix has been merged to PHP7.1, but cannot find more useful informations, since the bugtracker says "PHP version: irrelevant".

Answer (score 1):

A user-contributed note in http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php specifies the following:

> *"Emulated prepares work more stable in this cases, because they convert everything to strings and just decide whenever to quote argument or not to quote."*

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php#119956

Comment: my programming knowledge is limited. Possibly a silly question, but I read articles suggesting to avoid MySQL auto typecasting as much as possible. But when we use PDO, for integer types, we have to then depend on mysql typecasting (string to int). is this a good approach?

Comment: @Kiran it's not a silly question. I believe this post https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24378/type-casting-variables-in-php-what-is-the-practical-reason-for-doing-this will explain it faster than I, as would https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13776/if-we-cast-a-value-is-it-still-necessary-to-escape-it-with-mysqli-real-escape-st - which would depend on its application. If any of the approaches work, then by all means, do.

Comment: @Kiran there is one thing though when dealing with integers, is to make sure that you're not passing a possible octal. One such as `$var = 01;` would fail in having a leading zero, should this be relevant, and would require it to be quoted. I.e. `$var = '01';`

Comment: oh this looks interesting indeed. the links u shared are very informative.

Comment: @Kiran "Casting" though, would be necessary though when having to deal with converting integers to strings and other possible uses. Here are a few references https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html --- http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cast/

Comment: @Kiran However, when using a  MySQL function such as `IN()`, and dealing with integers specifically, you would need to specify the param related to an int. One such as `WHERE 
 (expr|column_1) IN ('1','2',...);` would fail on an `int` type column since those are considered as string literals https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html rather than a pure integer  `WHERE 
 (expr|column_1) IN (1,2,...);` - Quite a few things to take into consideration. I hope this helps shed a bit more light on the subject. `IN()` can work with strings but the param would need to be specified.

Comment: yes, i now understand functions like IN when it accepts integers in comma separated form can cause issues when used with PDO like you mentioned. I was trying to test his behavior using bindParam now

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: just to add, tested and seen that bindParam also work in same way

Comment: @Kiran That would mean that this is happening at the core level of PDO's data processing, not just for `bindValue()`.